# Linking href in Material UI Drawer Component in dynamic website

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, navbar

I'm trying to use Material UI's drawer component (https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/) to set up a navigation bar. As I'm using this code for the project, I'm not sure exactly how to link the href properly so the user can click on the home menu button and routes to a different page. I have used history.push in each function for different pages I have created, but not sure how to link it up.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Drawer, Button, List, Divider, ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText, AppBar, IconButton, Toolbar, Typography, Collapse } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import SortIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Sort';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';
import LockOpenIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOpen'; // log in
import ExitToAppIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp'; // sign out
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle'; //user profile?
import GroupIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Group'; // team 

import AccountBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountBox';
import wecycle from '../images/wecycle_logo.PNG';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    main: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        /*height: "100vh",*/
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
    },
    navbar: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    navbarContent: {
        width: "100%",
        margin: "0 auto",
    },
    navbarTitle: {
        fontSize: "2rem",
        flexGrow: '2',
    },
    icon: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: "2rem",
    },
    colorText: {
        color: "#5AFF3D",
    },
    container: {
        textAlign: "center",
    },
    title: {
        color: "#fff",
        fontSize: "2.5rem",
    },
    list: { //NEW
        width: 250,
    },
    fullList: {
        width: 'auto',
    },
    wecycleLogo: {
        width: "115px",
        height: "50px",
    }
}));

/**
 * The code line 63 to 147 is composed of Material UI Drawer Component code. 
 * Please refer to https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/ for 'Temporary Drawer'
 * 
 * @returns header 
 */
export default function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const {currentUser, logout } = useAuth();
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const history = useHistory();

    function aboutUsRedirect() {
        history.push("/aboutUs");
    }

    function landingRedirect() {
        history.push("/");
    }

    function loginRedirect() {
        history.push("/login");
    }

    function signupRedirect() {
        history.push("/signup");
    }

    async function handleLogout() {
        setError('');

        try {
            await logout();
            history.pushState("/");
        } catch {
            setError("Failed to log out");
        }
    }
    
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        right: false,
    });

    const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        }

        setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
    };

    const list = (anchor) => (
        <div
            className={clsx(classes.list, {
                [classes.fullList]: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom',
            })}
            role="presentation"
            onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
            onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        >
            <List>
                {['Home', 'Log In', 'Sign Up'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <HomeIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['Profile', 'About'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <AccountBoxIcon /> : <GroupIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div className={classes.main} id="header">
            <AppBar className={classes.navbar}>
                <Toolbar className={classes.navbarContent}>
                    <h1 className={classes.navbarTitle}>
                        <img src = {wecycle} className={classes.wecycleLogo} />
                    </h1>
                    <IconButton>

                        {['right'].map((anchor) => (

                            <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
                                <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>
                                    <SortIcon className={classes.icon} />
                                </IconButton>

                                <Drawer anchor={anchor} open={state[anchor]} onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}>
                                    {list(anchor)}
                                </Drawer>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ))}
                    </IconButton>

                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to connect your redirect functions to the UI elements, or asking how to render `Link` components into the mapped menu options, or maybe something else?

Comment: Hello. The first one, where I want to connect the redirect functions to UI elements. When the user clicks on the button, it routes to the link provided. (ex. user clicks on About us button and routes to '/aboutUs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the callbacks to the `ListItem` component.

```
<ListItem button onClick={clickHandler}>
  <ListItemIcon>
    <IconComponent />
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText primary={text} />
</ListItem>
```

You can optimize your item mapping by moving more data into the array being mapped.

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    text: 'Home',
    icon: HomeIcon,
    onClick: () => history.push("/"),
  },
  {
    text: 'Log In',
    icon: MailIcon,
    onClick: () => history.push("/login"),
  },
  {
    text: 'Sign Up',
    icon: HomeIcon,
    onClick: () => history.push("/signup"),
  },
];

...

<List>
  {menuItems.map(({ text, icon: Icon, onClick}, index) => (
    <ListItem button key={text} onClick={onClick}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <Icon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={text} />
    </ListItem>
  ))}
</List>
```

Comment: Thank you! I eventually solved on my own but will look at this code for future references :)